# AVL Tree implementation: Insert function - Reference get twisted

Tags: javascript, algorithm, data-structures

I got the bug when adding 13 to the tree, the left and right pointer of node 10 have reference back to the root, and create cycle reference.

I think it's because I understand Javascript syntax wrong.

[code](https://codesandbox.io/s/avl-tree-qj7dj) (open the console)

```html
function rotLeft(node) {
  const parentNodeCopy = copyObj(node);
  const parentRightLeftChild =
    node.right.left !== null ? copyObj(node.right.left) : null;
  parentNodeCopy.right = parentRightLeftChild;

  node = node.right;
  node.left = parentNodeCopy;

  return node;
}

function rotRight(node) {
  const parentNodeCopy = copyObj(node);
  const parentLeftRightChild =
    node.left.right !== null ? copyObj(node.left.right) : null;
  parentNodeCopy.left = parentLeftRightChild;
  node = node.left;
  node.right = parentNodeCopy;

  return node;
}

function rebalance(node) {
  const bFact = threshold(node);

  if (bFact > 1) {
    if (threshold(node.left) < 0) node.left = rotLeft(node.left);
    node = rotRight(node);
  } else if (bFact < -1) {
    if (threshold(node.left) > 0) node.right = rotRight(node.right);
    node = rotLeft(node);
  }

  return node;
}

function insert(node, val) {
  if (node === null) return;

  if (val <= node.val) {
    if (node.left !== null) insert(node.left, val);
    else node.left = new TreeNode(val);
  } else {
    if (node.right !== null) insert(node.right, val);
    else node.right = new TreeNode(val);
  }

  return rebalance(node);
}
```

Any suggestion?

Comment: What are the inputs, sequence of function calls, expected outputs? Can you post the code where you are calling these functions?

Comment: Debugging, even with pen and paper, should work. If you get stuck post you debug-output and where you cannot follow why happens what happens.

Comment: That will be the brute-force approach and not guarantee you found the solution (i.e Einstellung effect). The better approach is find someone accept my lengthy, stupid arguments and point right out where is the crack.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you don't use the returned node reference from the recursive call of `insert`. `insert` may return a different node than the one it got as argument. By not assigning it back to `node.left` or `node.right`, the latter will keep a reference to the non-cloned node, giving you an inconsistent tree.

So change this:

```
if (node.left !== null) insert(node.left, val);
```

to this:

```
if (node.left !== null) node.left = insert(node.left, val);
```

Do the same with the mirrored case.

### Other remarks

Unrelated to your question:

1. It should not be necessary to create clones of nodes. Rotations can be implemented by just mutating the existing nodes.
2. Retrieving the height dynamically each time you need it will kill the performance of this implementation. It is better to store the height as a property of a node and keep it updated. The best is to store the balance factor. With some nifty logic you can keep the balance factors up to date without having to query the heights of nodes. It is possible with just knowing the balance factor of the children, and which rotation is being performed.

Comment: I haven't found anyone talk about "Retrieving the height dynamically kill the implementation" yet, I just see people take for granted. I have thought: Why update while saving information need update too?

Comment: Retrieving the height dynamically at each node you visit (with `rebalance`) will redo the count that you might just have done for a child node of that node (as you call `rebalance` while stepping out of the recursion), ... the number of nodes that gets visited and revisited with all those counts will be enormous. Keeping a `count` property updated will only require an update of O(logn) nodes per insert/delete.

Comment: Also, do you know where to ask code review, question about this kind of my question (code review, data structure...)? I don't know what forum is more actively than stackoverflow.

Comment: There is [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/)